# How to parse a date in Java?

Tags: java, date, parsing, exception

Hi I have a file with a number of dates written in rows. I am extracting that date field and then trying to parsing them in Date object. I am using Java. The date is in the following form:

"13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM"
and my code snippet as follows:

```
String rpattern = "d MMM, yyyy - hh:MM aa"; //13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM
SimpleDateFormat rsimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(rpattern);
Date rtime = rsimpleDateFormat.parse(report_time.trim());
```

The program works fine for few dates except 31 Oct, 2017 - 5:31 PM. It flags an exception for this particular date (31 Oct, 2017 - 5:31 PM) as follows:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "31 Oct, 2017 - 5:31 PM"
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at Analysis.SnarlVicRoadIncidentReporting.main(SnarlVicRoadIncidentReporting.java:54)

Can anybody help me to get around this issue?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the name of the months should be given in the language of your locale, not English?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously full of surprises. The good solution is to skip that class and its outdated friends and use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were probably running into localization issues.

The abbreviated month names (`"Nov"`, `"Oct"` in your case) are language-dependent.

The `SimpleDateFormat(String)` constructor created an instance using 
the system default `Locale`, which may be German for you, thus expecting
`"Okt"` (for German Oktober). But your String contains `"Oct"` (for English October).

The solution is simple. Use the [SimpleDateFormat(String, Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) constructor, i.e.

```
SimpleDateFormat rsimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(rpattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat rsimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(rpattern);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. See [the Answer using modern java.time classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491052/642706).

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo: pattern is: "d MMM, yyyy - hh:**mm** aa"

all parsing is wrong because of that. Yours picks a month from  hh:MM, so there is no month as 31, while for November date it returns month as March, because what suppose to be a minute is 03

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated, and judging from the number of questions on Stack Overflow, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is causing trouble for many. In recognition of the fact that the old classes were poorly designed, `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API was launched in the spring of 2014. It’s much nicer to work with, so I recommend you use this instead.

Let’s try an experiment: I use your format pattern string with the modern API (there are differences in the format pattern string syntax, but much is the same).

```
    String rPattern = "d MMM, yyyy - hh:MM aa"; //13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM
    DateTimeFormatter rDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(rPattern);
    String reportTime = "13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM";
    LocalDateTime rDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(reportTime, rDateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(rDateTime);
```

This gives `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: a`. The modern API is stricter with the number of letters, for better and for worse. Its error messages are generally helpful; in this case it’s straightforward to follow what it says:

```
    String rPattern = "d MMM, yyyy - hh:MM a";
```

Now I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM' could not be parsed at index 3`. Index 3 is where it says `Nov`. As Thomas Fritsch already said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47488264/5772882), this is a locale problem. Let’s fix:

```
    DateTimeFormatter rDateTimeFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(rPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

We got further: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM' could not be parsed at index 15`. Index 15 is where the hours are, `7`. We had specified `hh`, that is, two digits, but there is only one. One `h` will accept both one-digit and two-digit hours:

```
    String rPattern = "d MMM, yyyy - h:MM a";
```

Now it’s getting tricky: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13 Nov, 2017 - 7:03 AM' could not be parsed at index 17`. Index 17 is the minutes. You may have to study the docs carefully to discover what Vadim already said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47488181/5772882): uppercase `M` is for month, lowercase `m` for minutes. Fix:

```
    String rPattern = "d MMM, yyyy - h:mm a";
```

Hey, this time we succeeded:

```
2017-11-13T07:03
```

To sum up, `DateTimeFormatter` is stricter, which may annoy at first, but it has two clear advantages: You get better validation of your formatter; and you also get better validation of your date-time string.